# Coherance Rest API with encoding data

Tags: caching, oracle-coherence

I'm new to oracle coherence and i just want to know are there any possibility to use PUT method and save the data in encoded way and decode the data when retrieve using Coherence API.Sample will be enough to proceed.

refereed this article for Coherence API.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24290_01/coh.371/e22839/rest_api.htm#COHCG5241

Answer (score 0):

For that purpose you can use [Network Encryption Filters](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14526_01/coh.350/e14509/networkfilters.htm#COHDG151) to make your clustered communications protected.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. i just want to enrypt and dectypt the data on the fly in coherence cache.

Comment: That's what exactly these filters for.